# extjs chart->series change color dynamically

Tags: extjs, charts

How can dynamically change a chart.series.color?

I sthere any way to change a color for "ONE" bar to draw attention?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

I use this code, but the gradient is seen in the back not in all the bar:

see this image: [chart image](http://adan.co.il/charttt.jpg)

```
var enroll = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    width: 430,        
    height: 250,
    xtype: 'chart',
    renderTo: 'O20_id-body',
    store: store1,
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['data1'],
        label: {
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        },
        title: 'Number of Hits',
        grid: true,
        minimum: 0
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['data1'],
        title: 'Month of the Year'
    }], 
    gradients: [{
    id: 'redGradient',
    angle: 45,
    stops: {
        0: {
            color: '#FF0000'
        },
        100: {
            color: '#F0F0F0'
        }
    }
  }],        
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        axis: 'bottom',
        highlight: true,
        xField: 'name',
        yField: 'data1',
        renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
                     //draw diffrent color                                         
                     sprite.setAttributes({fill: 'url(#redGradient)'}, true);
                     return attr;

        }
    }]

});
```